# react-day-picker without overlay (input field only)

Tags: reactjs, react-day-picker

Wanting to leverage some of the built in functionality (date validation, etc) of [react-day-picker](http://react-day-picker.js.org/) while not offering the calendar overlay (offering the user an input field without the calendar overlay).

I'm not seeing any options in [the docs](http://react-day-picker.js.org/docs/getting-started) to show only the input field without the calendar overlay.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a hacky way but I can see that you can provide custom prop `classNames` to the `DayPickerInput` component. [Source](http://react-day-picker.js.org/api/DayPickerInput/)

And you could provide an object like

```
<DayPickerInput>
    classNames={{
       overlayWrapper: 'myCustomClass'
    }}
/>

.myCustomClass {
    display: none;
}
```

or if you can hide the default class for the overlay wrapper

```
.DayPickerInput-OverlayWrapper {
    display: none!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nope, looking into the [source](https://github.com/gpbl/react-day-picker/blob/master/src/DayPickerInput.js) but it's open source. You can copy the file and remove the parts you don't need.